# Xmpp Openfire CallbackOnOffline 1.2.0 not working

Tags: plugins, push-notification, xmpp, openfire

Before 1.2.0 I am using 1.0 version and it was working fine but after the update, the new version 1.0 to 1.2.0 and there is some changes in callback URL like getting to Post. I have made all the changes and I can able to the call back URL is triggering from XMPP server but it was not calling my server side.

I can able to see logs till line 112:

[Xmpp File](https://github.com/igniterealtime/Openfire/blob/master/src/plugins/callbackOnOffline/src/java/com/fotsum/CallbackOnOffline.java#L112)

After 122 logs are not showing in XMPP log.

Can anyone have done the CallbackOnOffline 1.2.0?

Please help me out with the problem.. if anyone has a solution about it.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

I am facing same issue with 1.2.0 version, so I am suggesting you can use old version 1.0 instead of 1.2.0 for now.

[CallbackOnOffline.jar 1.0](https://github.com/krunalsojitra/xmpp-CallbackOnOffline)

Let me know if it will not works.

Comment: thanks krunal, you save my life.. I am trying to find version 1.0 jar but I did't fine even from xmpp igniterealtime.
Thanks a lot!